# Setting the Visiblity of Tables based on a variable in a loop

Tags: javascript, adobe, sap-basis, livecycle-designer, adobe-form

I have a Table Looping over structure that have elements. 
One of these elements is the type, that should be used to determine the visibility of the tables inside of the loop (1 Table should be visible)

In the java script, I tried to assign this value to a variable and compare it with the Type but no luck.

Something like this didn't actually work,
initializing with visibility set to hidden.

```
var x = $record.main.table[*].typ ;
  if ( x == "03" ) {
  this.prescence = 'visible';
}
```

Setting another textfield to this value actually shows the value.

I tried everything with single quotes and double quotes,
invert the process by using != and so on..

Comment: edit : typo....

Comment: show form context and its hierarchy

Comment: So here is the hierarchy: the red pointer is for the whole loop, I did that by using the option in "Options"-> Binding and loop checkbox ( I have the UI in german so its little hard to translate) 

and on every table -> initialize i wrote the script.

![](https://i.imgur.com/4qUzCtf.png)

and the yellow pointer is for the tables

Comment: it's not actually clear what is your task and your problem, what are you trying to hide? tables? text fields or something else? maybe your whole approach is wrong?